# How to configure Stylus support in a React.js application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, create-react-app, stylus

I want the classes in my React.js application to be available for export from `.styl`-files in the same way as it can be done from CSS Modules, but I can't find any ready-made solution to this problem.

I found [a guide to setting up CSS Modules](https://www.triplet.fi/blog/practical-guide-to-react-and-css-modules/) in an application created with Create React App.
I understand that you need to run `npm run eject` and somehow rewrite configuration files,
but how – I don't understand.

Comment: Have you tried https://www.npmjs.com/package/css-modules-stylus ? (Take a look at `Babel Plugin` section)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to install next npm-packages in your project:

- [stylus](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stylus)
- [stylus-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stylus-loader)
- [css-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/css-loader)

In webpack.config, in section `module` you need to add next points:

```
{
  test: /\.styl$/,
  use: [
    'style-loader',
    'css-loader?modules&camelCase&localIdentName=[path]__[name]__[local]--[hash:base64:5]',
    'stylus-loader',
  ],
},
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  use: [
    'style-loader',
    'css-loader',
  ],
},
```

Then you can import your styles from .styl files in your React components like this:

```
import style from './СomponentStyle.styl';
```

and you can use style by CSS name for example:

```
className={style.container}
```

where `container` - it is name of CSS but without dot. For complicated names like: `.container-btn-green` you need write next code: `style.containerBtnGreen` or `style['container-btn-green']`

Answer (score 2):

**Run-time solution** ( without eject )

install react-rewired and customize-cra to have an option to update config on run-time

```
npm i react-app-rewired
npm i customize-cra
```

create file *config-overrides.js* in the *package.json* folder with content :

```
const {
    override,
    addWebpackModuleRule
  } = require("customize-cra");

module.exports = override(
    addWebpackModuleRule({
      test: /\.styl$/,
      exclude: /(node_modules)/,
      loaders: [
        'style-loader',
        {
          loader: 'css-loader',
          options: {url: false}
        },
        {
          loader: 'postcss-loader',
          options: {
            ident: 'postcss',
            plugins: (loader) => [require('autoprefixer')()]
          }
        },
        'stylus-loader'
      ]
    }),
    addWebpackModuleRule({
      test: /\.css$/,
      use: [
        'style-loader',
        'css-loader',
      ]
    })
);
```

install stylus

```
npm i stylus
npm i stylus-loader
npm i css-loader
```

change your start / build scripts to use react-rewired

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-app-rewired start",
    "build": "react-app-rewired build",
...
```

Then you can import your styles from .styl files in your React components

```
require('./style/index.styl');
```

OR

```
import style from './СomponentStyle.styl'; --> className={style.container}
```

This all :) Additional thanks to *Denis Bubnov* in current topic - you helped me much to implement current solution!

Comment: Hi Konstantin, I tried using your approach but as soon as I try to import a .styl file I get the following error:

```
./src/app.styl (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-1-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/stylus-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/app.styl)
TypeError: this.getOptions is not a function
```

... some googling suggests that this might be caused by the webpack version that CRA uses. Have you come across this error before?

Comment: Okay, I think I solved it: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/stylus-loader/releases/tag/v5.0.0 -> after downgrading to stylus-loader@v4.3.3 it works as expected.

Comment: Will try to use stylus-loader and update the solution....

Answer (score 1):

Here is the link to configure stylus with create react app

https://github.com/flexzuu/create-react-app-styl

Answer (score 1):

I like Surya's approach.

1. install stylus with

```
npm install stylus --save-dev
```

2. Create 2 folders `/src/styl` and `/src/css`
3. Drop some files into `/src/styl`.
4. Add the following scripts to your `package.json`:

```
    "stylus:watch": "stylus -I ./node_modules -w ./src/styl -o ./src/css",
    "stylus": "stylus -I ./node_modules ./src/styl -o ./src/css"
```

5. Run `npm run stylus:watch` in a second terminal. It will watch all files in `/src/styl` and compile them to css in `/src/css` where they will be picked up by your React dev server.
6. Before building your react app, make sure to run `npm run stylus` one last time.

Answer (score 0):

### This is how I made it work

1. Create a React-Parcel project
   i) first create a parcel project ([Get started](https://parceljs.org/getting-started/webapp/)) 
   ii) Add React to your parcel project ([Add React](https://parceljs.org/recipes/react/))
   iii) Optional: Add typescript to your parcel project ([Add Typescript](https://parceljs.org/languages/typescript/))
2. Add Stylus to your React-Parcel project
   ([Add Stylus](https://parceljs.org/languages/stylus/))

### What is Parcel?

- Parcel is a tool that lets us combine the technologies we love. In other words, it is a JS bundler.
- And the best part is that we don't need to eject stuff and we don't need to install webpack.
- It currently supports the most popular technologies such as:

  - Vue
  - React
  - Pug
  - Graphql
  - SugarSS
  - Stylus
  - Less
  - Sass
  - Typescript
  - Coffeescript
  - Elm
  - And more!
- It is scalable, lightning-fast and very popular. I effeminately recommend it.